# Continuent tungsten to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate, tungsten-replicator

We are working on one project where we required Oracle data to be stored at Cassandra. For storing the data in Cassandra we are proposed to first get the data from oracle to apache kafka MQ server then did manipulation with spark and save into cassandra. For real time data replication from oracle to Apache Kafka is available Due to heavy license cost we are looking for ***Continuent Tungsten*** which is open source.

Has anybody some idea if we can directly transfer incremental data from Tungsten to kafka?